# How to write an exponent into a textview?

Tags: android, character-encoding, textview, exponent

I would like to use an exponent like this programmatically in a textview:

[image: example image for m^3]

Is it possible, and if yes, how?

Edit: got it, thanks for helping!!

```
SpannableStringBuilder dataset = new SpannableStringBuilder(dataset2[position] + " m3");

dataset.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), dataset2[position].length() + 2, dataset2[position].length() + 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
dataset.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.75f), dataset2[position].length() + 2, dataset2[position].length() + 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

holder.mTextView2.setText(dataset);
```

Comment: I guess you can use a web view and use an HTML tag to do superscript

Answer (score 1):

Try Html.fromHtml instead. Simple and precise:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("m<sup>3</sup>"));
```

Comment: Doesn't work, think because I'm not setting the text directly, but putting it first into a array and reading it out later. `results[i] = parserXML.parseStringForText(data, "Size", "WebShipment", position) + Html.fromHtml("m<sup>3</sup>");` Is it possible to put it somehow into the string array or is it just possible to set it directly on the textview?

Comment: Please show your code for setting text to textView.

Comment: Was doing it like this: `holder.mTextView2.setText(dataset2[position]);`, but it does not show the exponent correct. Tried this `holder.mTextView2.setText(dataset2[position] + Html.fromHtml("m<sup>3</sup>"));`, still not showing the exponent correct. Just this one shows it correct, but it's without additional strings, which I need: `holder.mTextView2.setText(Html.fromHtml("m<sup>3</sup>"));`.

Answer (score 0):

I this u have to use like this.

```
your_textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("m<sup>3</sup>"));
```

Or

[Use this too](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/SuperscriptSpan.html)